# Can a conditional variable "miss" a notify call?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I was wondering if it were possible for a conditional variable to "miss" a notify call. My scenario is as follows.

Given a mutex mu, and a Pred P (!queue.empty())...

Thread A: Persists for the entirety of the program's life span. Holds a conditional variable waiting on mu and P. Upon acquiring mu and verifying the queue is not empty, it will pop an item from the queue.

Thread B: A function that will acquire mu, push to the queue.

Thread C: Same as B.

Thread B and C are spawned simultaneously.

In this scenario B acquires mu first, pushes to the queue, drops mu and calls notify. In between B calling notify and dropping mu, C acquires mu, pushes to the queue, and calls notify. Finally A acquires mu, proceeds to pop an item from the queue and process it. However A only acts on one of the notify calls.

If you are trying to process the items in the queue one by one, this seems to create a pile up.

Is this a situation that can occur? And do we have to be aware of it? For example, within A, pop UNTIL the queue is empty? Or is this handled by the language?

Comment: As you say, pop until the queue is empty. Condition variables don't keep track of how many notify calls are pending.

Comment: What's the problem with A acting on only one of the `notify` calls? What do you think A will do next?

Comment: The issue is if A doesn’t act on both notify calls, I have items in the queue I’m not processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are trying to process the items in the queue one by one, this
>   seems to create a pile up.
>
> Is this a situation that can occur? And do we have to be aware of it?
>   For example, within A, pop UNTIL the queue is empty? Or is this
>   handled by the language?

Yes it is a situation that can occur and you should be aware of it.  In your described scenario, the wait could wake once (with two items in the queue), twice (once per item in the queue) or even N times (spurious wakeups with no items in the queue.  This is why *you always check your predicate after waking and then make sure the predicate is false prior to re-waiting on the condition*.  Popping until the queue is empty is a reasonable solution.

Comment: When waking, the predicate is checked on cv.wait(lock, verify_pred), to avoid issues with spurious wake up. However at this point I still need to handle the fact that there may be more than one item in the queue that must be processed. Do you see any other reasonable alternative, other than just popping until the queue is empty before waiting again?

Comment: cv.wait() will return immediately when your predicate is true (i.e. not block) regardless of whether it was notified. Thus if the predicate is (!queue.empty()) or something similar, and there are two items in the queue, it's going to return immediately until the queue is empty (not necessarily the number of notifications it gets!) and go around twice. So you probably don't need to do anything other than pop the queue once when wait() returns as wait() will continue to return immediately until the queue is empty. What exactly is your predicate?

Comment: And sorry I didn't go into detail before - I'd assumed you were using pthreads.  Boost or C++ threads changes the dynamics a little.

Comment: C++ threads, and so that's where my confusion lies. My predicate is {return !queue.empty()}. My understanding is that even though the predicate is satisfied, it blocks at wait until it acquires the lock, or is that wrong? In which case, that's also not what I want.

Comment: Ok, you should have the lock acquired *before* you call wait, that's a precondition of using wait.  *Wait then unlocks the mutex and waits after it checks the predicate*.  If the predicate is false, it returns with the lock still locked.  And yes, once unlocked, it will wait until signalled (or spuriously woken) and then reacquire the lock before returning.

Comment: Right, so I think we are on the same page now, I would just need to ensure the queue was empty before releasing the lock.

Comment: @nromer It shouldn't matter whether you check if the queue is empty or not before releasing the lock. Whatever consumer thread next gets the lock should find the queue non-empty and not wait for anything. Just don't wait for something that has already happened.